# Android geocoding by gps lat long

Tags: android, reverse-geocoding

in my android app i calculate gps position and show the lat log value into TextView, and i use this lat long value for a query on SQLITE DB.
Now i'm trying to show into TextView the name of Location calculated by lat and log. I have try geocodeby i have soma error.
this is my code for calculate the lat and long value:

```
ImageView  bt_get_mygpspos = (ImageView)getView().findViewById(R.id.bt_get_mygpspos);
                edittext_mygpspos = (EditText)getView().findViewById(R.id.edittext_mygpspos);
                bt_get_mygpspos.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        GPSTracker mGPS = new GPSTracker(getActivity());
                        if(mGPS.canGetLocation() ){
                            query.curPos = new LatLng(mGPS.getLatitude(),mGPS.getLongitude());
                            edittext_mygpspos.setText("lat:"+query.curPos.latitude+" lon:"+query.curPos.longitude);
                            Log.e("test", "lat:"+query.curPos.latitude+" lon:"+query.curPos.longitude);
                        }else{
                            mGPS.showSettingsAlert();
                        }
                    }
                });
```

how i can trasform the mGPS.Latitude and Longitude in a name of Location to show into TextView?

Thans

Answer (score 0):

You could use any public web-based `API` for geocoding like:

- [Google](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro) `API`;
- [Yandex](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/geocoder/desc/concepts/input_params-docpage/) `API`;

`Yandex` is better in ex-USSR space and have better daily free limits: 25 000 request when compare to 2 500 in `Google`. In any other detail `Google` is better.